# Display Javascript Parsed Objects with Line Breaks using For/In

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript function that parses DynamoDB items (which are strings) into objects. I want to output each object onto my HTML page as its own separate line.  I thought one of the ways is to identify the last item in the object from my for/in loop, then add a line break.  However, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
function displayObj(dataStr){
    var obj = JSON.parse(dataStr);
    var html = "";
    var item =;
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var last = keys[item.length - 1];

    for (item in obj){
        html += '<li>' + item + ' ' + obj[item] + </li>';
        if (last == true)
            html += '<li>' + item + ' ' + obj[item] + </li>' + "<br>";
    }
    return '<ul>'+html+'</ul>';
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting should give you a hint of at least one of your issues. What errors are you getting in the web console?

Comment: `if (last === item) ...`

Comment: You cannot have children in `ul` other than `li`.

Comment: Summer, I have neither errors in my web console nor syntax highlighting errors.